# browser doesn't request to vscode xdebug server

Tags: php, xdebug

I Try to use xdebug in Windows 10.

I had used xdebug in My Mac machine.

But, In windows 10, I installed xdebug 2.9.8 then config it.

It does not work as I thought.

Below is my `php.ini`

```
; XDEBUG Extension
[xdebug]
zend_extension = c:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.33\ext\php_xdebug.dll
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = Off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.remote_host='127.0.0.1'
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.log="c:/wamp64/logs/xdebug.log
```

I confirmed it was intalled correctly using `php -v`

Then I installed php-debug extension in my vscode.

and then my apache vhost is like below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName hello.localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/hello"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/hello/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is all my settings about debugging php.

My expectation is to trigger browser to xdebug server running in vscode When I request to my apache hosts `hello.localhost`.

But It does not work.

I confirmed any other script worked well for debugging scripts such as debugging current scripts and built-in server configs automatically configured in php-debug extension.

I wanna to try is Listen for xdebug script in vscode. It does not work.

What does I have to configure more?

[image: xdebug]

[image: xdebug2]

And below is my vscode configure for xdebug.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9003
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Post your 1) PHP and Xdebug versions used right now 2) current Xdebug config from php.ini 3) The actual live config (the WHOLE Xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output for Xdebug v2 or `xdebug_info()` if Xdebug v3 is used 4) Your VSCode debug config (what you are using to start the debug session) 5) Enable Xdebug log (`xdebug.log`), try to debug and see what it has to say (where it tries to connect to (if at all) and what the response is).

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you have first well linked your vHost with your Xdebug

You should then have `xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1` or `xdebug.client_host=hello.localhost` enabled in your `PHP.INI`.

Also make sure that you have disabled Zend OPCACHE extension.

```
[opcache]
;zend_extension="C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.33\ext\php_opcache.dll"
```

Call `xdebug_info();` on a PHP page and verify all these settings.

Finally, call the page you want to debug by adding `?XDEBUG_SESSION=1` to your querystring or call `xdebug_break();` directly in your code.

Comment: I disabled OPCACHE, so I enabled it.  then I try to set client host to 127.0.0.1 or hello.localhost, localhost.
vscode xdebug still doesn't listen from browser request.
I have executed xdebug_info(). It emitted error.

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function xdebug_info()`

I have confirmed that my php extension is enabled for xdeubg and OPCACHE using `php -v`.

Thank you for responding my question.

Comment: @JayLee The OPCACHE extension must be **disabled** like in my code sample, with a semi colon prior the line. Try again. Can you also call a phpinfo() and see what’s below xdebug? It’s not normal the xdebug_info() is not responding.

Comment: I misunderstood it, sry
I disabled it again, but it is still not working. xdebug_info() is alreday undefine function. I thinks It was something wrong in my config or server settings.

Comment: @JayLee: Don't give up. Can you post your `php.ini` block part related to Xdebug, and can you post your `phpinfo()` result in your original question? 

Wamp already has the right dll for Xdebug, so it's not the issue. There must be a small config detail remaining somewhere. Are you behind a firewall that could block ports 9000 or 9003? Can you also check if there is any error in your Php or Apache logs?

Comment: Have you enabled this `xdebug.log="c:/wamp64/logs/xdebug.log"` as well?

Comment: Yes, I added picture in my original question.

Comment: I change to my php version to 7.1.33 and xdebug 2.9.8

Comment: I have been using windows pc in company and mac in my home.
mac is works well as I expected, but I don't know why it is not work in windows wamp64 environment.

Comment: @JayLee : **We still miss the important part of your phpinfo()** (about Xdebug port, enabled or not, etc.). Without this part, it will be hard to find. In the meantime, I understand now that you are using Xdebug v2.x and my answer was about v3.x. Can you then get back to your initial php.ini (with Xdebug v2 original settings) and remove the v3 specific settings which are useless. In v2, please put this in your php.ini `xdebug.remote_enable=1`.

Comment: ok, When I go to my company next week, I share my xdebug and php.ini config.

Comment: I added picture for phpinfo() and my xdebug configs in php.ini.

Comment: sorry I had mistaked my port for listening in xdebug. I changed my port to 9003 in xdebug and vscode configure. It works well now thank you.